# Knexjs update with orderBy upon returning

Tags: sql-order-by, knex.js

How can I set the order of values on the return values of an update in Knexjs?

I have a table where I have to update a certain column and return all those rows by order of its creation date. I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
let notifs = await db('notification')
    .where({receiver_id : id})
    .update({marked : true})
    .returning("*")
    .orderBy("notif_date", "desc")
```

Is this possible or do I have to make 2 separate queries for `update` and `orderBy`?

Answer (score 0):

[Update](http://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#update) returns the affected rows, updating one with `id` and using `returning` gives back a single result

if you are on the back-end you need two separate queries you update and then you query for all rows

there are things you can do on the front-end where you take back the single result that has updated and insert it into an already cached query  on the client but that is a whole other topic